# [] followed by () in regex altering the meaning of [] in python

Tags: python, regex

My **regex** expression is `re.findall("[2]*(.)","b = 2 + a*10");`

Its **output**: `['b', ' ', '=', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', 'a', '*', '1', '0']`

But from the expression what I can infer is it should give all strings starting with o or more times 2 followed by anything, which should give all characters including 2! But there is not 2 in the output? It is actually omitting the characters inside [] which I concluded after replacing 2 with any other character But unable to understand why it is happening? Why [] followed by () omitting characters inside [].

Comment: Use raw strings: `re.findall(r"[2]*(.)","b = 2 + a*10")`. Also why the `;`?

Comment: Why downvote????

Comment: @Jerry What would a raw string change?

Comment: it should give all strings starting with at least 0 times 2 - I believe you didn't mean to say "at least 0 times 2", coz that makes zero sense ;)
Please rephrase your question so that it's clear what you want to do.

Comment: @Pixel It does make sense, though it does sound weird in regular English.

Comment: @JoshLee Just a good habit to have, since it can change the outcome of certain expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs for `re.findall`:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
>   list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.

So when you include `(.)` in your pattern, `re.findall` will return the contents of that group.

Comment: Thanks. But why not returning 2?

Comment: Because that's matched by `[2]*`, which is not inside your `(...)` group.

Comment: Why does `' ='` match `[2]*(.)` but not `' 2'`?

Comment: @deceze : `' ='` doesn't match `[2]*(.)`, but `' '` and `'='` match separately. The reason the 2 is ommitted is that `'2 '` matches `[2]*(.)`, but only the space is in the returned group. The `'2'` part of the match is excluded. In all other characters the `'2'` is matched 'zero' times and the character is in the returned group.

Comment: @deceze Add a character after the `2` so the two is matched then the group can match. Otherwise it doesn't match (As `(.)` doesn't have any characters left) and then it matches `[2]{0}(.)` (Where the `.` is the 2).

Comment: @deceze - In your example the 2 is the last character. so it is not " 2" that is matching - if you read the text to the right it is purely "2" that is match 4 and the 2 is in the group returned. However that is not the case in the example above. If you add another character, such as a space as in the example above, after the 2 in your given example the website you use also does not return a '2'  as the 2 is no longer in the returned group. The explanation is right there on the page if you give it the correct input data. The 'fullmatch' becomes `'2 '` but the returned group is just `' '`

Comment: @R.Sharp Why does the engine *forego* the ` 2` match in this scenario? I'm looking for an explanation involving a keyword like "greedy" or whatever rule is at play here.

Comment: @deceze because the regex is looking for 0 or more 2's followed by any single character. `' 2'` is a space followed by a 2 and thus cannot be described as zero or more 2's followed by any single character - it's a character followed by a 2. It has nothing to do with 'greedy'. Greedy would ensure that 2222222z only produced one match `'2222222z'` and not a match for 22, 222, 2222, 22222 222222 and 2222222 as well. Unless specified otherwise - matches are greedy.

Comment: @R.Sharp So something like that should be part of the accepted answer. `' 2'` is a valid match where the group matches `2`, then why does that behaviour change when adding one more character even though it could match `' 2'` *and* `'2 '`?

Comment: @deceze. Sorry, no `' 2'` is not a valid match. the group may match '2' as 2 is any character but the space is not a '2' so it cannot match the regex as a whole. The regex then moves on to the next character in the string, which is just a `'2'` - that matches as zero 2's followed by a 2 and so matches - but that is not the case in the example provided in the question - it was the case in the example you provided the website.

Comment: @deceze -2 ...Where the 2 is followed by another character (anything) the regex considers the 2 to be a match of 1 '2' and looks for a following character - whatever that character is matches the 'goup' and only the group is returned - the 2 is discarded. May I suggest you read some online explanations of how a regex match is performed because without a small character limit they will be able to explain it much better than I. Basically the regex looks at the first char in a string and trs to match it to the first element of the regex.

Comment: @deceze : If no match, it moves to the next char in the target string. If there is a partial match, it considers the next char in the target string to see if there is a match to the next element of the regex.

Comment: @deceze : `' '` is zero 2's followed by a space - match ; `' 2'` is a space, not a 2, followed by a 2 - no match. ; `'2 '` is one 2 followed by a charcter - space so the space is in the returned group. The only match you can get that returns a 2 is when 2 is the last character. Then it matches as zero 2's followed by any character, a 2 in this case. But if the 2 is followed by any other character the 2 becomes one of the  2's in the non-returned part of regex. Like I say - read some tutorials on regexes and go back to that website and give it the full string in the example, it behaves the same

Comment: @R.Sharp I'd strongly encourage you to write an answer…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154229/discussion-between-r-sharp-and-deceze).

Comment: See : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html particularly  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things and https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping.